# Insert getdate() into column

Tags: php, sql, getdate

I am trying to put a timestamp on when a new line is added to my database, (for displaying it later on, kind of like a blog).

Here's my code right now, but it won't register the date.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `Content` (postContent, datePosted) VALUES ("'.(string)$content.'", "'SELECT getdate()'")';
```

What is the right syntax of getdate() in this situation?

EDIT: this is in php, also the date has to be associated with the "Content".

Thanks.

EDIT2: I am a goof, I could have just put CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in 'default' in MySQL and it would have automatically have done it. Please resort to this if you attempt it yourself instead of spending over 2 hours trying to fix this manually like me.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

your passing like a string replace it like this.

you just remove the double quotes and single quotes from query

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `Content` (postContent, datePosted) VALUES ("'.(string)$content.'",SELECT getdate())';
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as I did with the solution above. I can't seem to work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `Content` (postContent, datePosted) VALUES ("'.(string)$content.'",SELECT getdate())';
```

With this code:

```
$date = getdate();

$sql = "INSERT INTO `Content` (postContent, datePosted) VALUES ('".$content."', '".$date[0]."')";
```

The value that will be stored in datePosted has the following format:

> Seconds since the Unix Epoch, similar to the values returned by time()
>   and used by date().

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

What this means for you is that you will be able to easily compare your database value by either creating a `$currentDate = getdate()` or even easier by just comparing it to `time();` which as the exact same format.

Let me know if that helped!

Answer (score 0):

insert into [table_name] ([column_name]) values (now())